# JavaFX binding Label with int value

Tags: java, binding, javafx

I want to bind JavaFX `Label.textProperty` with `int` value.

I tried e.g.

```
Label.textProperty().bindBidirectional(new SimpleIntegerProperty(myInt), 
                                                      new NumberStringConverter());
```

or

```
Label().textProperty().bindBidirectional(new SimpleIntegerProperty(myInt), 
                                                              new DecimalFormat());
```

But I always get **NullPointerException**.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Any reasons for using Bidirectional binding on Label?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Possibly because it allows one to provide a `StringConverter`. I tried that before I found you can use `integerProperty.asString()` with a unidirectional binding as you pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have an int you can create a SimpleIntegerProperty from it and then use the `asString()` on it :

```
label.textProperty().bind(new SimpleIntegerProperty(integer).asString());
```

If you have an IntegerProperty, you can directly use it

```
label.textProperty().bind(integerProperty.asString());
```

Comment: Additional tip: you can use the overloaded version of `asString( String format)` that takes a format to do additional formatting of the number.

Comment: The result is formatted according to the formatting String. See `java.util.Formatter` for formatting rules.